# IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(intent) returns null, FireBaseUIAuth

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, idp

I am using FirebaseUI Auth to authenticate users with gmail. I am signing to with my gmail. In onActivityResult I check result code and it is RESULT_OK. Although when I create IdpResponse from intent, I get null and I can't check whether it's a new user or not.

I have added google-services.json in the application, also added libraries and plugins in gradle.

here is my code :

```
    fun promptUserSignIn() {
        val providers = arrayListOf(AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())

        startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(
                providers
            ).build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }

    @Override
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(intent)

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response: $response intent: $intent")
            }
        }
    }
```